# Building a Model using MVC 5 optimally that is Database friendly?

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc, sql-server

I'm using MVC 5 Core on my Web API and I wanted to know what is the most optimal way of storing an Array into a database? Should I store Arrays, does it matter, or should I parse the array and input them individually into their own separate rows?

By optimally, I mean being able to have more control over the data and cutdown on load times. Should I be inputting Arrays into a database or parse them and put them in separate rows?

Database: MSSQL

This is my model code

```
    namespace backend.Models
{
    public class Portfolio
    {
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public string ProjectRole { get; set; }
        public string ProjectTech { get; set; }
        public string[] ProjectDescriptions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "optimal?"  That is unanswerable unless you tell us what your specific criteria is.

Comment: Edited to be more accurate.

Comment: That's a classic 1:N data mapping. Any modern ORM can map that easily for you, even Linq2SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming you have an RDB) You should create another table and put each array item in it as a row.

Don't try and reinvent the wheel with xml columns or string parsing. The RDB is designed to store and retrieve this kind of data as related tables.

Answer (score 0):

`Portfolio` has a one to many relationship with `ProjectDescriptions`.  That's the structured database way to look at this.  You can hack around that in a multitude of ways but if you want to be friendly to a structured SQL database that's the deal.

There are other kinds of DB's that don't even have rows but MSSQL isn't one of them.

Load times aren't going to care about structure as much as amount of data.  As for control, my watchword is readability.